# Google sheet countifs multiple criteria range with checkboxes

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, checkbox, filter, countif

I am trying to display itemname+image once a checkbox is ticked in. If a checkbox is ticked twice, the item should be displayed two times - 3 times if all checkboxes for one item are ticked.

Current function doesn't work:

```
ifna(filter(BT!A5:B,BT!C5:C),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(BT!A5:B,BT!D5:D),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(BT!A5:B,BT!E5:E),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!G5:H,BT!I5:I),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!G5:H,BT!J5:J),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!G5:H,BT!K5:K),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!M5:N,BT!O5:O),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!M5:N,BT!P5:P),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!M5:N,BT!Q5:Q),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(Hyjal!A5:B,Hyjal!C5:C),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(Hyjal!A5:B,Hyjal!D5:D),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(Hyjal!A5:B,Hyjal!E5:E),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!G5:H,Hyjal!I5:I),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!G5:H,Hyjal!J5:J),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!G5:H,Hyjal!K5:K),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!M5:N,Hyjal!O5:O),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!M5:N,Hyjal!P5:P),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!S5:T,Hyjal!U5:U),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!S5:T,Hyjal!V5:V),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!S5:T,Hyjal!W5:W),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!M5:N,Hyjal!Q5:Q),if({1,1},char(999)))}, 
countifs(Hyjal!C:W,true,BT!C:W,true),,2,1)
```

If I split the function for each sheet and try it, it works.

```
ifna(filter(Hyjal!A5:B,Hyjal!C5:C),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(Hyjal!A5:B,Hyjal!D5:D),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(Hyjal!A5:B,Hyjal!E5:E),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!G5:H,Hyjal!I5:I),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!G5:H,Hyjal!J5:J),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!G5:H,Hyjal!K5:K),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!M5:N,Hyjal!O5:O),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!M5:N,Hyjal!P5:P),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!S5:T,Hyjal!U5:U),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!S5:T,Hyjal!V5:V),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!S5:T,Hyjal!W5:W),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(Hyjal!M5:N,Hyjal!Q5:Q),if({1,1},char(999)))}, 
countif(Hyjal!C5:W37,true),,2,1)
```

And for the sheet BT I used

```
ifna(filter(BT!A5:B,BT!C5:C),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(BT!A5:B,BT!D5:D),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(BT!A5:B,BT!E5:E),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!G5:H,BT!I5:I),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!G5:H,BT!J5:J),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!G5:H,BT!K5:K),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!M5:N,BT!O5:O),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!M5:N,BT!P5:P),if({1,1},char(999))); 
ifna(filter(BT!M5:N,BT!Q5:Q),if({1,1},char(999)))}, 
countif(BT!C5:Q73,true),,2,1)
```

So, I tried to combine those 2 functions with `countifs`, changed the column criteria range to C:W in the formula but it only displays items from the sheet Hyjal once items from the Sheet BT are checked. Items from BT itself are not displayed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hsCZMn1rif2eWpjShWBCH9kCLbSBEA66ZWjDwjhbyGE/edit?usp=sharing

The formula is in the BT+Hyjal Sheet in B3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SORT(IFNA(FILTER(
 {Hyjal!A:B; Hyjal!A:B; Hyjal!A:B;
  Hyjal!G:H; Hyjal!G:H; Hyjal!G:H;
  Hyjal!M:N; Hyjal!M:N; Hyjal!M:N;
  Hyjal!S:T; Hyjal!S:T; Hyjal!S:T;
  BT!A:B; BT!A:B; BT!A:B;
  BT!G:H; BT!G:H; BT!G:H;
  BT!M:N; BT!M:N; BT!M:N}, 
 {Hyjal!C:C; Hyjal!D:D; Hyjal!E:E;
  Hyjal!I:I; Hyjal!J:J; Hyjal!K:K;
  Hyjal!O:O; Hyjal!P:P; Hyjal!Q:Q;
  Hyjal!U:U; Hyjal!V:V; Hyjal!W:W;
  BT!C:C; BT!D:D; BT!E:E;
  BT!I:I; BT!J:J; BT!K:K;
  BT!O:O; BT!P:P; BT!Q:Q}=TRUE)), 2, 1)
```

[image]